# read a json response in a html/js file

Tags: javascript, json

Is the below possible.

I am getting a ajax response below:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<input type="text"></input>
<div id="trydiv"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "json.php",
        data: 'val='+$('input').val(),
        success: function(response){
            $('#trydiv').load("try1.js");
        }
    });
```

**json.php**

```
<?php 
echo json_encode($_POST['val']);
?>
```

**try1.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        alert(response);
    });
</script>
```

Since in the success function, 'm passing response, should "response" not be available for try1.js. Is there anyway we can pass response to a js/html file and use in that?

Comment: have you tried? i dont think it will pass this way

Comment: it didnt.. 
but 'm wondering there is anyway i can get the json response and pass it to a html/js file so i can read in it..

Comment: I think u need to put the response in some div and call that div after some load

Comment: `data: 'val='+$('input').val()` should be `data: {val: $('input').val()}`

Answer (score 0):

No, `response` will not be available, unless you assign `response` to a global variable (and assuming browser security lets you load such scripts dynamically). I think it would be helpful though if you clarify more about what you are trying to achieve and why.

Also, maybe you just did it for formatting, but a file try1.js should not have script tags inside of it.

Comment: i am trying to build a html/js dynamically using the values in json response

Answer (score 0):

today i came across an very interesting script that showed me how to take parameters from the script tag:

```
$.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(response){
            $('#trydiv').load("try1.js");
            var scr = document.createElement('script');
            scr.type = 'load.js?'+escape(response);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
        }
    });
```

Now inside your load.js:

```
// get the parameters from the script tag
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var data ='';
for (var i=0,l= scripts.length;i<l;i++){
   if (scripts[i].src.indexOf('load.js') != -1){
      data = scripts[i].src.slice(scripts[i].src.indexOf('?')+1);
   }
}

// now you can do alert the data
alert(data);
```

This might seem complicated but study it a little and you will see i can help you with your particular problem

Comment: yup.. what u were suggesting is to append the json object as a js file in head.. 
if that be the case, we can write json to a file in php using fwrite and use $.getScript('response.jsonFile')..
cant we? 
anyways, i am not sure which will give a better performance.. any advice on this?

Comment: the one advantage i know about this method is that it works with crossdomain script